# iOS 8 (Xcode 6.1.1) - Navigation bar not working as in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm just following a YouTube tutorial [Swift iOS Tutorial - Core Data - Add Update Delete PART1 (Xcode 6 Beta)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ymz6i07DRM&list=PLuZEqxdBDSXGH6_8S5jc-0javTMQhRtx5) that was done in different Xcode version and encountering navigation issues that wasn't apparent in the tutorial. I suppose this is something to do with changes in latest Xcode that I hope some one might be able to address here.

I have one TableViewController with embeded in NavigationController (initial view) and from the TableViewController, I made a push segue from `+` bar item to another ViewController. In simulation mode, this `+` button displays as `Edit` and clicking this doesn't go to the ViewController it should push to.

This is how it's done in storyboard.
[image]

And, this is the simulation screen that the button is wrong and clicking this doesn't go to the next screen.

[image]

**UPDATED

[image]

Comment: which one is your root view controller, if Recipes is your first view controller r u embed in Navigation controller, and show your Edit button action method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Recipes is the first view controller and Navigation is embedded in. I made `add` button, not `edit` button but it displays as `edit`. And for this simple exercise, it doesn't look like there is any action method required as per the tutorial I followed as this is just UI exercise and functionality part comes next.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad`, did you uncomment `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()`?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Yes, I have uncommented it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

check the segue connection, if you have given it to cell, if there is a record then only it navigate to the next view. other wise give a segue connection to the edit button to next view for testing purpose.

Comment: I have already created a segue connection to the `+` button to see if it redirects to the AddViewController but it doesn't work even for testing purpose.

Comment: may be the segue connections are went wrong. please check it once. try this if you select segue connection, then that will indicate that where it is coming the link segue. it might helpful i think so!!!

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of the segue connection. Thanks!

Comment: Nice hint, you have implemented in split view application. so only you are getting this issue. better you go for "single view application" then you may easily navigate your UI. we can edit/add a record in split view within detail view controller. so no need to navigate another ui like which you posted first screen shot.

Comment: When I created this project, I chose single view application so I'm not sure how this is in split view application? I don't even get split view application as an option when creating a new project. Any idea on how this can be changed to a single view application?

Answer (score 1):

This is why I don't like storyboards. I suggest doing it programatically.

Here's how you could do it in your `viewDidLoad` function:

```
var navPlusButton = UIBarButtonItem()
navPlusButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "+", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "myAddFunction")
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navPlusButton
```

Then you'll just make a function outside your viewDidLoad called `myAddFunction` or whatever you call yours.

```
func myAddFunction() {
    var VC = addVC()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
}
```

You would probably replace the above with a segue instead of a pushViewController, if you are using storyboards. :)